# Umbraco with MVC Area - System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I have an umbraco site with an MVC area.
I started getting this error:
[image]

Is there any package to update?

Comment: I cleared all folders: ExamineIndexes, DistCache, PluginCache, ClientDependency in TEMP folder.
I cleared all cache also but still the problem persists

Comment: Read the stack trace, set a break point in your code (or set the debugger to stop on the exception)

Comment: The luceneindexer and everything pertaining to Umbraco is in a dll. I do not have the source code for that. How can I debug? I can debug only the source code that I have, the homecontroller, gloabal.asax..etc.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the umbraco.config file from the file system and republishing the whole site?

Comment: May be you need clear Lucene indexes or reindex for Lucene examine to work again https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140717101312-18294893-umbraco-lucene-index-corruption